# Compare SQL Server database schema

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, schema, compare

I am working on project (VS2010 .NET) and have two SQL Server databases, `Dev` and `Prod`.

I make all database structure changes in the `Dev` database and after testing I apply the same changes to the `Prod` database.

Maybe someone could suggest schema comparison tool which could help me to compare structure and apply changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedGate makes excellent tools for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I know of two really good tools:

- [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)
- [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can also get [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) (free) here - more about SSDT on [my blog](https://lynnlangit.com/2011/11/21/sql-server-2012sql-server-data-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

although you are working in 2010, if you can get hold of VS 2012

go to SQL (menu item) -> Schema Compare. Click on Select Source on the left, and select the dev database. Select the production database on the right.

Then click on the generate script icon (next to the Update icon, it looks more or less like a music icon). That will generate the update script. You may also untick any of the changes that you do not want to include in the script. And it is ... 'free' if you happen to own Visual Studio 2012